# Android Java Communication over USB

Tags: java, android, usb, communication

I'd like to send a object/string from Android device to PC in Java over USB. It is possible?
Basically a client/server over USB.

Actually, using the emulator, I can access the server socket via the special 10.0.2.2 address.
Over Wi-fi, i can access with 192.168.1.X address.
And over USB, how it works?

According to [this](http://android.serverbox.ch/?p=370), I guess it's possible but, how I do the sample code in java instead of python? any ideas?

```
private Byte[] bytes
private static int TIMEOUT = 5000;
private boolean forceClaim = true
UsbManager manager = (UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
HashMap<String, UsbDevice> deviceList = manager.getDeviceList();
Iterator<UsbDevice> deviceIterator = deviceList.values().iterator();
while(deviceIterator.hasNext()){
    UsbDevice device = deviceIterator.next()
    UsbInterface intf = device.getInterface(0);
    UsbEndpoint endpoint = intf.getEndpoint(0);
    UsbDeviceConnection connection = mUsbManager.openDevice(device); 
    connection.claimInterface(intf, forceClaim);
    bytes = toByteArray("any path");
    connection.bulkTransfer(endpoint, bytes, bytes.length, TIMEOUT); 
}


public static byte[] toByteArray(File file) throws IOException { 
   ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 
   boolean threw = true; 
   InputStream in = new FileInputStream(file); 
   try { 
     byte[] buf = new byte[BUF_SIZE]; 
     long total = 0; 
     while (true) { 
       int r = in.read(buf); 
       if (r == -1) {
         break; 
       }
       out.write(buf, 0, r); 
     } 
     threw = false; 
   } finally { 
     try { 
       in.close(); 
     } catch (IOException e) { 
       if (threw) { 
         log.warn("IOException thrown while closing", e); 
       } else {
         throw e;
       } 
     } 
   } 
   return out.toByteArray(); 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use text file.

Save the text file in your sdcard. Then in your PC java program, execute `adb pull` command.

This way if your phone is connected to your PC over USB, the file will be pulled from the phone to the PC upon the `adb pull` execution.

Of course need to have adb in your PC and USB debugging allowed in you phone.

Hope this helps.

Regards